# How to make a Push Notification opens a specific uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've been trying forever to get this to work, when I send a push notification to my app. When the user opens it, it just takes them to the app. I want to direct them to a specific uiview, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is called if your app is running (whether in the background or not).

So that would be the starting point to direct them to the specific `UIView`.

You can tell whether your app was just brought to the foreground or not in the code in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099483/how-to-respond-to-push-notification-view-if-app-is-already-running-in-the-backgr)

Hope this helps .