# How to launch app automatically on recieve local notification without click on notification ios

Tags: ios

I want to launch my application without any click on notification.Is it possible in ios?

Comment: No, it's not possible if by "launch" you mean opening the app. What you can do is to run a process on it, but on background.

Comment: How can i run app on background?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099483/how-to-respond-to-push-notification-view-if-app-is-already-running-in-the-backgr

Comment: Please give it up, you could not do that.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do it, maybe this can be done on jaibreak devices but it's can not be done on original devices.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is impossible as of now in iOS devices.
2. Even it is possible, it is considered as a bad user experience practise.