# Which callback get executed when my app is openned from a push

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Hi there i would like to know which app delegate method get called when my app launch from a push notification (When the app was previously in the background ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the *didReceiveLocalNotification:* method in your *AppDelegate*.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

    // Handle the notification here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056689/didreceiveremotenotification-when-in-background) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)