# cannot receive push notification when app is not running

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've created an iphone app with push notification feature. The server works well and I could receive the notification when app is running in foreground. The function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is called then notification arrives. 
However, when I press the home key, brought the app into background or kill it in the task bar. I cannot receive any notification, neither in the notification area or any popup.

Anyone knows the reason? Thanks

Comment: Did you check the notification center? In the settings of the device, go to Notifications -> you app name, see if you have notifications enabled as popup, banner or none.

Comment: I checked it, it's all enabled.

Comment: @ErenBeşel: did you find solution? im facing same issue.

Comment: @user836026 I wasn't the one having the issue. As for you though, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056689/didreceiveremotenotification-when-in-background) would help

Answer (score 1):

You can use...

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dicItem = [dic objectForKey:@"aps"];
        NSString *itemNotification = [dicItem objectForKey:@"alert"];
    }else if (launchOptions == nil){
        NSLog(@"launch ,,, nil");
    }
...//code something
}
```

itemNotification is an item in Notification barge. Have fun!!