# Receiving Push Notifications while in background

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know this is covered in a lot of places, but I cannot figure this out.  I use Urban Airship for push notifications. Everything seems to be fine except that when my app is in the background - `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not getting called. It works when in the foreground - I am able to properly process messages. And I am able to get to messages from launch options if message is tapped from notifications center. But when in the background, a message it send - iOS displays the alert - `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called. When I tap on my Application icon (not from within notification center) the app comes to the foreground and I have no idea the notification is present. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the APNS programming guide :

> Let’s review the possible scenarios when the operating delivers a
>   local notification or a remote notification for an application.
>
> The notification is delivered when the application isn’t running in the
>   foreground. In this case, the system presents the notification,
>   displaying an alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound.
>
> As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action button
>   of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon. If the action
>   button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the
>   application and the application calls its delegate’s
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it
>   passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the
>   local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application
>   calls the same method, **but furnishes no information about the
>   notification**.

I believe the last sentence describes your case, and explains why your application gets no information about the notification.

Comment: Yep - I missed that. Well - that sure sounds like a real shortcoming. I suppose there are ways around it - but would be really straight forward for iOS to provide this. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Is there other way to take information for push notification,when click application icon?I need one value,that is in payload.

Comment: @Eran , do you mean when app is background running, then taps the notification alert item, the app will not call the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`?

Answer (score 50):

`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` will call in the background only when you have added `content-available` key with value `1` into the notification payload.
In case of the Urban Airship, you can send Test Push under the Setting tab.
Sample Payload for Push Notifications:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "aaaa",
    "badge": "+1",
    "content-available": "1"
  },
  "device_tokens": [
    "86BA71E361B849E8312A7B943BA6B26A74AB436381CF3FEE3CD9EB436A12A292"
  ]
}
```

Apple has clearly mentioned in his documentation....

> For a push notification to trigger a download operation, the
>   notification’s payload must include the content-available key with its
>   value set to 1. When that key is present, the system wakes the app in
>   the background (or launches it into the background) and calls the app
>   delegate’s
>   application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
>   method. Your implementation of that method should download the
>   relevant content and integrate it into your app.
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Also, per the documentation, the "Remote notifications" option needs to be enabled in Background modes under Capabilities in the target settings.

Comment: hmhm I use Google Cloud Messaging, they also implement content-available, on receiving (when clicked notification) the output tells me that content-available is outside the `aps` object. And ofcourse it ain't working for me. :( Apple why so difficult...

Comment: This answer must be marked as the right answer indeed.

Comment: i am also working with the same scenario but i am using FCM . i am also stuck like you that i could not open push notification until i tap on the notification message . do you have any idea regarding how to solve this with FCM ?

Comment: May be following link is helpful.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: `"content-available": "1"` is actually very important.

Answer (score 6):

didReceiveRemoteNotification is calling ONLY if app in foreground or if app is just launched or is bought from background to foreground

[link in Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and some [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056689/didreceiveremotenotification-when-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

Method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** parameter launchOptions one of the dictionary keys are ***UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey*** which holds the pressed push notification info.

You can push received info after tour main root controller is initialised. I save it to some property and then push it after view is initialised.

```
if (launchOptions) {
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
        self.notificationToMakeAction = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    }
}
```