# Receiving and handling notifications via app icon launch - ios

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How do I access the notification if the app is not running and I launch it via the app icon with the badge number on it? Is there a way to request it from the server. I am using parse.com.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving Push Notifications while in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616261/receiving-push-notifications-while-in-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what correctly your question, that if you app receives a push notification and the user doesn't tap on on the notification alert, but the app icon, how to get the information from that notification. The simple answer is that you can't. [This is from the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)

> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the
>   application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about
>   the notification . If the application icon is clicked on a computer
>   running OS X, the application calls the delegate’s
>   applicationDidFinishLaunching: method in which the delegate can obtain
>   the remote-notification payload.

So if the user opens the app from the springboard icon you won't get any information about it.

I'm not sure how your Parse db is setup but if you don't have unique users, and your push notifications go out to everyone, just have the app check the server for updated_at dates on the push notifications you've sent out.

Comment: Thanks, now I have to learn how to check the server for updated_at dates.

Comment: @BrainzOutDeh No worries, it should be relatively easy using PFQuery.