# How to handle launch options in Swift 3 when a notification is tapped? Getting syntax problems

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am trying to handle the launch option and open a specific view controller upon tapping a remote notification that I receive in swift 3. I have seen similar question, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757362/open-a-view-controller-when-a-ios-push-notification-is-received), but nothing for the new swift 3 implementation. I saw a similar question (and ) In AppDelegate.swift I have the following in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    var localNotif = (launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! String)
if localNotif {
    var itemName = (localNotif.userInfo!["aps"] as! String)
    print("Custom: \(itemName)")
}
else {
    print("//////////////////////////")
}
```

but Xcode is giving me this error:

```
Type '[NSObject: AnyObject]?' has no subscript members
```

I also tried this:

```
   if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        var notificationPayload: NSDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary!

    }
```

and I get this error:

```
error: ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'
```

I got similar errors wherever I had previously used similar code to get a value from a dictionary by the key and I had to replace the codes and basically safely unwrap the dictionary first. But that doesn't seem to work here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So it turned out the whole method signature has changed and when I implemented the new signature things worked just fine. Below is the code.

new didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {



//and then 
 if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {


// Do what you want to happen when a remote notification is tapped.


}

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 34):

Apple made plenty of changes in `Swift 3` and this one of them.

Edit: **This works for Swift 4 as well.**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Launched from push notification
    let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any]
    if remoteNotif != nil {
        let aps = remoteNotif!["aps"] as? [String:AnyObject]
        NSLog("\n Custom: \(String(describing: aps))")
    }
    else {
        NSLog("//////////////////////////Normal launch")
    }
}
```

**Swift 5:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Launched from push notification
    guard let options = launchOptions,
        let remoteNotif = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any]
        else {
            return
    }
    let aps = remoteNotif["aps"] as? [String: Any]
    NSLog("\n Custom: \(String(describing: aps))")
    
    handleRemoteNotification(remoteNotif)
}
```

And for more on `LaunchOptionsKey` read Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey).

Comment: I still get the error , ambiguous reference to member subscript!

Comment: my bad, there was a mistake. try now

Comment: Hmm, thanks but you sure you updated your response? seems to be the same

Comment: Yes I have made a couple of changes. They are very minor that's why they aren't evident.

Comment: So as I mentioned in the answer above it turned out the whole signature of didfinishwithoptions method has changed. Thanks for your comments again.

Comment: Tried the Swift 5 solution but I am not getting value for the "remoteNotif". Any reason why this is happening. Except when app is killed in all other scenarios I am getting push notifications.

Comment: @subin272 this code is for the case when app is killed and is launched through a notification. Can you share any further details to investigate the issue?

Comment: @Adeel yes I am trying the same scenario you mentioned ie the app is killed. Then trying to launch it from push notification. I am checking it with an if else condition.

Comment: @Adeel.  if let options = launchOptions,
            let remoteNotif = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any]
        {
            UserDefaults.standard.set("From remote", forKey: "NotificationPayload")
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set("xyz", forKey: "NotificationPayload")
        }

Comment: Is there any other way to verify the contents of "launchOptions" or test remote notifications when the app is killed?

Comment: @subin272 its a strange behaviour. Can't really say why it might be happening.

Comment: @Adeel Found a solution for this..seems its an iOS 13 issue. Link to the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007715/launchoptions-always-nil-when-launching-from-a-push-notification

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 4

```
// Check if launched from the remote notification and application is close
 if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] {
            // Do what you want to happen when a remote notification is tapped.
            let aps = remoteNotification["aps" as String] as? [String:AnyObject]
            let apsString =  String(describing: aps)
            debugPrint("\n last incoming aps: \(apsString)")
    }
```

Comment: How to pass this notification object in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get what you mean, can you elaborate more so i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

swift 3:

```
        if let notification = launchOptions?[.localNotification] as? NSDictionary{

            #if DEBUG
                print("iOS9 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions notification\n \(notification)")
            #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any] {
       if let notification = remoteNotif["aps"] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
               //handle PN
       }
}
```