# Why ambiguous reference to member 'Subscript'?

Tags: ios, swift3, appdelegate, remote-notifications

This is my Swift 3 code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let userInfo : Foundation.NSDictionary = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? Foundation.NSDictionary {
        self.setNavigationInfoFromPushNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        navigateFromPushNotification()
    }
    ...
}
```

It results in a compile-time error that says:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'Subscript'

Please can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Yes, this code is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions only.

Comment: Can you please also include your current method signature for `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` ?

Comment: @Rob Or it might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209234/how-to-handle-launch-options-in-swift-3-when-a-notification-is-tapped-getting-s

Comment: `launchOptions` seems to be `Any?` and must be casted to a dictionary. And in Swift do not annotate types the compiler can infer and do not use `NSDictionary` unless you have no choice (here you have).

Comment: Yes, correct. I changed the syntax for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. It is working well. Thankyou !!

Comment: From func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

Comment: @Keiwan - Yep, you're right. This turned out to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209234/how-to-handle-launch-options-in-swift-3-when-a-notification-is-tapped-getting-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature has changed. See [How to handle launch options in Swift 3 when a notification is tapped? Getting syntax problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209234/how-to-handle-launch-options-in-swift-3-when-a-notification-is-tapped-getting-s).

It is now:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool { 
    if let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary {
        setNavigationInfoFromPushNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        navigateFromPushNotification()
    }
    ...
}
```