# App crashes after push notification is tapped when app is killed

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to launch a specific viewController in my CustomTabBarController after receiving remote notifications. But somehow, the app always crashes when the app is killed.

Meaning to say, kill the app -> received push notifications -> tap the notifications -> app launches and crashed. This also happens when I tap the notification from the lockscreen.

I am able to execute when the app is in the background, but not when the app is killed. My code so far:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    ...
    
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary {
        guard let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? CustomTabBarController else {
            return true
        }
        rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1
        
    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if application.applicationState == .background || application.applicationState == .inactive {
        
        guard let rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? CustomTabBarController else {
            return
        }
        rootViewController.selectedIndex = 1
    }        
}
```

I've followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940629/how-to-open-specific-view-controller-when-push-notification-received-in-swift-3) to check the launchOptions, but it still crash. What can I try next?

Comment: @matt how do I get the log? The console is terminated when the app is killed. Sorry I'm actually pretty new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment these 2 lines

```
// window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
// window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

as overriding the window property destroys the initialization from storyboard (makes rootVC nil) and before `return true` window must have one

Comment: I don't use storyboard. I do my views programmatically.

Comment: Apologies, I just tried your code and it actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am using REACT Native.