# How do I open a particular view controller in a tab bar when a FCM push notification is tapped?

Tags: swift, push-notification

The app keeps crashing whenever I tap the push notification when the app is closed. If it's in the background or open when I tap the push notification then it loads just fine.

I've tried the suggestions over here: [Swift - How to open specific view controller when push notification received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940629/swift-how-to-open-specific-view-controller-when-push-notification-received)

Below are the relevant functions in the app delegate. Any print functions to determine where exactly the crash is caused is not being registered so I cannot debug properly. The only message I see is:

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        // Navigation customization
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(hex: Constants.Colors.primary)!, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "NexaLight", size: 18)!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
        
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(hex: Constants.Colors.primary)!, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "NexaBold", size: 18)! ], for: .highlighted)
        
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(hex: Constants.Colors.secondary)!, NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "NexaBold", size: 18)! ], for: .focused)
        
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application( application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions )
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        }
        
        // Firebase
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // APN FCM
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        // Stripe
        StripeAPI.defaultPublishableKey = "test"
        
        // Google sign-in
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "test"

        return true
    }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


    if let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window {
        guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else { return }
        if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? MainTabBarController {
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
            window.rootViewController = tabBarController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } 
    }

completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is, you are extracting the rootViewController from window. But when app is closed, there is no rootViewController associated with the window. So you are not setting any rootViewController, but window needs a rootView to show content , that's why your app is crashing.  But when app is in background or active state it's working because you are getting a rootViewController from window, did you get my point ?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. It looks like I'm doing the same thing as you've indicated below from your answer in the other thread except that I am not using storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to my explanation

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if let window = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window {
        if let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController {
            if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? MainTabBarController {
                tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
                window.rootViewController = tabBarController
                window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        } else {
            let tabBarController = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainTabBarController") as? MainTabBarController
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
            window.rootViewController = tabBarController
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```