# Why tap on remote notification misses navigation to desired screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, remote-notifications, didreceiveremotenotification

when i tap on push notification when app is in killed state it don't navigate to desired screen but when it is active state or foreground state it working perfectly.
but sometime it also navigate in killed state.

need proper solution.
thanks.

Comment: follow this below link this will helps you that how to set root view controller or navigate in app after tap on remote notification
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940629/swift-how-to-open-specific-view-controller-when-push-notification-received

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.