# How to open a specific view controller from App Delegate on didReceive Push Notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, uikit

I'm trying to open a specific view controller when notification is tapped. and i'm unable to do so any one who can help me with it?

[I have attached the view controller image which i'm trying to open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tsV1.png)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    //when notification is tapped
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

print("USERINFO : \(userInfo)")


let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let apptVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VideoChatViewController") as! VideoChatViewController
          let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: apptVC)
          self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
          self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - How to open specific view controller when push notification received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940629/swift-how-to-open-specific-view-controller-when-push-notification-received)

Comment: Yes this does help me. but i already figured it out myself. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

After set rootViewController you need to set navigation for that

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    println("didReceiveRemoteNotification")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MessageViewController") as MessageViewController

    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```