# ios How to launch application in push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am facing issue in launch of particular application page when user will get push notification in ios.

is this possible to do?

if yes, can you please help me in that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a view controller when a iOS push notification is received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757362/open-a-view-controller-when-a-ios-push-notification-is-received)

Comment: By launch of application page, you mean to open the app? Elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

You could send a notification to yourself when you get any remote notification and by registering the `UIViewController` to this notification, you could open a particular `UIViewController` once notification is received.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

}
```

In your FirstViewController.m register for listening to this notification.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{  

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushNotificationReceived) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];

}
```

Inside the method you could open particular viewController

```
-(void)pushNotificationReceived{

 [self presentViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Finally un-register current viewController from notification in dealloc method

```
-(void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Let me know if you face any problem with this.

Comment: Checking. Thank you for quick help.