# How to do routing from AppDelegate.swift to any View controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If a user is already logged in, I want to open my `HomeViewController`; and if a user clicks on a push notification, I want to open my `NotificationViewController`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:    [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // What's code write for this functionality.

    return true
    }
```

Xcode 11.3.1
iOS 13

Comment: You can go through this for reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757362/open-a-view-controller-when-a-ios-push-notification-is-received/20757676

Answer (score 0):

Open home controller if already logged in :

[https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/?fbclid=IwAR0A4SIzTZSyXhx8wEfgW9ZpBpO9LPwL39VdGEVpP9O-vjoUPk_ly7Z9ZQQ][1]

Click on push notification and move to notification view controller :

[https://fluffy.es/open-app-in-specific-view-when-push-notification-is-tapped-ios-13/?fbclid=IwAR11wi4EniJspDi_i45BtgZ1hWqGesonAReayOBccH7chJ0cKBRfAkmcI0w][2]