# didReceiveRemoteNotification: is not called after notification arrives and app is in background/suspended mode

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Within `AppDelegate` I simply update `applicationIconBadgeNumber`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
}
```

Everything works as expected when the app is connected to Xcode and is **in debugger mode**. But just after I plug it out from Xcode, notification arrives but badge is not updated. App is **in background mode**.

Why? What is wrong with my approach? Please, give me an advice

Answer (score 4):

Push notification are handled by iOS and not your app you can't change the application badge on receiving a push notification.
You can send the badge number in the payload of the push notification,

Payload could look like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Notification REceived",
        "badge" : 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to manage badge count is on the server.
A push notification will automatically update the badge on the app icon.

Payload formate.

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Weather report udapted",
        "badge" : 5
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. My delegate method is not called when app is in background mode and not connected to the debugger;)

Comment: Have you confirm delegate UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self inside application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method

Comment: Yes, I can confirm;) That method is called when app is connected to the debugger, but doesnt work when not connected to the debugger. Why?

Comment: What makes the difference with that two methods?;)

Comment: Hello @BartłomiejSemańczyk my didreceiveremotenotification method is called when app is put in background by content available 1. but after some time the method stops getting called no matter how many push i send. can you PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post very helpful for managing notifications in the background, basically you have to use the call with completion handler.

[didReceiveRemoteNotification when in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812162/3681879)

Answer (score -1):

Your `messagingManager` is an optional. You should check, that it isn't `nil`. If it is `nil`, the `appDidReciveMessage()` function would not be triggered

Comment: It is not nil;) it works when app is connected to the debugger

Comment: Did you check also that it isnt nil when your App is in Background?